# Microsoft Edge won't render the correct font

Tags: fonts, microsoft-edge, font-face, font-family, roboto

On all~~ websites, elements that with Roboto as font-family will instead render a courier-like font with missing special characters like ã or ç.

Inspecting one of the elements, it shows both in the Styles and the Computed subtabs:

`font-family: roboto, sans-serif`

The *rendered fonts* box shows **Courier — Local file (24 glyphs)**, instead.

Reinstalling all the Roboto family on the system has no impact. Using the inspector to remove `roboto` from the rule (leaving `sans-serif`) makes the elements impacted by the rule render correctly.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:

1. not all websites, actually. It seems related to those that try to use Roboto locally available, instead of, say, Google Fonts.
2. This is a sample website that goes wrong in Edge and shows correctly in Firefox: https://hospitalsaolucas.pucrs.br/br/institucional-pagina/interna/experiencia-do-paciente

**EDIT 2: I didn't do the websites. I'm not a webdev trying to debug websites, I'm a Edge user trying to figure out what's wrong with my system!**

Comment: Please add your `@font-face` rule and a minimal example HTML and CSS of your page. Local fonts can cause rendering issues in some browsers. So it's usually more reliable to strip any `local()` properties.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I added some further info. It is a remote website, not something I'm authoring. It is a Edge related problem, as it seems. Firefox renders it correcly.

Comment: The website shows "Error 1009, Access denied" when I open it. Please provide a minimal code snippet which can reproduce the issue so that we can have a test.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this error in edge. But you're right `local()` declarations in your `@font-face` rules  are infamous for causing conflicts with locally installed versions. So I highly recommend to strip these completely in your `src` properties. BTW it's quite odd the aforementioned characters are substituted – Portuguese is covered by googles/standard "latin" unicode range. You might also test your page in another chromium based browser like opera, brave, google chrome etc.